# How to embed a Rust macro variable into documentation?

Tags: macros, documentation, rust

I'd like to use a macro variable in the macro-generated documentation:

```
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($name:ident) => {
        /// Returns a new `$name`.
        fn myfoo() -> $name {

        }
    };
}
```

However, the variable won't be substituted. I also tried using the `#[doc]` attribute:

```
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($name:ident) => {
        #[doc = concat!("Returns a new `", $name, "`.")]
        fn myfoo() -> $name {

        }
    };
}
```

This one even fails to parse: `unexpected token: 'concat'`

Comment: @Shepmaster I couldn't find it, but I wonder why the second one fails to parse.

Comment: The set of allowed tokens inside an attribute is probably pretty limited.

Comment: @torkleyy Macros are not expanded when parsing (which is why there is [RFC 1628 "Eager expansion of macros"](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1628))

Comment: @Shepmaster I though procedural macros allowed any token in attributes now (but the `#[doc]` attribute itself won't know what to do with those).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This can be done using a recursive macro:

```
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($name:ident, $sname:expr) => {
        #[doc = "Returns a new `"]
        #[doc = $sname]
        #[doc = "`."]
        pub fn myfoo() -> $name {
            42
        }
    };

    ($name:tt) => {
        impl_foo!($name, stringify!($name));
    };
}

impl_foo!(u32);


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Which renders as:

[image: Example from rustdoc]

Comment: With rustc version 1.77.0 (nightly) using this pattern I get error: "Cannot parse doc attribute" at the line corresponding to `#[doc = $sname]`, any clues?

Answer (score 10):

While [the answer @mcarton gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43353854/4674154) does work perfectly fine for simple examples, it breaks a bit for more complicated ones. Rustdoc seems to insert spaces between the different `doc` attributes. The markdown processor strips them out most of the time, but sometimes, it transform them to spaces instead. Consider this example:

```rust
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($name:ident, $sname:expr) => {
        #[doc = "You can call this as `myfoo("]
        #[doc = $sname]
        #[doc = ")`."]
        pub fn myfoo(_: $name) -> $name {
            42
        }
    };

    ($name:tt) => {
        impl_foo!($name, stringify!($name));
    };
}

impl_foo!(i32);


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This should generate the documentation "You can call this as `myfoo(i32)`.", but in reality, it results in "You can call this as `myfoo( i32 )`." (note the additional spaces):[image: Screenshot from the rustdoc page showing the additional spaces]

I'm not too sure whether my solution would have worked with the 2017 rustc back when the question was asked, but in modern Rust, this can be done by combining [`stringify!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.stringify.html) with [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html):

```rust
macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($name:tt) => {
        #[doc = concat!("You can call this as `myfoo(", stringify!($name), ")`.")]
        pub fn myfoo(_: $name) -> $name {
            42
        }
    };
}

impl_foo!(i32);


fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

This results in the documentation you want (so, without superfluous spaces):

[image: Screenshot from the fixed rustdoc page]

Comment: While this works for `cargo doc`, rust-analyzer shows no comment this way. 