# Is there any way to inline a const inside a doc comment (rendered by cargo doc)?

Tags: rust, doc, cargo-doc

With "default" constructors, it can be useful to document what the… defaults are. If this is textually defined in the doc and separately defined as a literal or a static / const, the two can get out of sync:

```rust
impl Foo {
    /// Creates a [Foo] with a `bar` of 3.
    fn new() -> Foo { Foo::new_with_bar(5) }
    /// Creates a [Foo] with the provided `bar`.
    fn new_with_bar(bar: usize) -> Foo { Foo { bar } }
}
```

It's possible to extract the literal to a const or static and *link* to that, but then the reader has to go through the indirection to know what the value is, and the const / static has to be `pub` or `cargo doc` complains and refuses to link to it.

Is there any way to *substitute* the const value in the docstring instead of linking to it? Or some other method which would avoid the indirection? aka

```rust
const DEFAULT_BAR: usize = 5
impl Foo {
    /// Creates a [Foo] with a `bar` of ???DEFAULT_BAR???.
    fn new() -> Foo { Foo::new_with_bar(DEFAULT_BAR) }
}
```

should be rendered as:

> ```
> pub fn new() -> Foo
> ```
>
> Creates a [Foo](http://example.org/foo) with a `bar` of 5.

Although similar, [How to embed a Rust macro variable into documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353077/155423) doesn't seem to apply here. `[doc]` complains about an unexpected token when given a name as a parameter (even a const str) and I don't know if a wrapping macro can force the substitution of a const.

Comment: *and the const / static has to be pub* — Aside from your question, I actually think that's a good thing. In similar cases, I want to modify the default (double it, for example) or use one default value and one non-default value. Having public values for those unlocks those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in Rust 1.47:

```
struct Foo { bar: usize }

macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($bar_def:expr) => { impl_foo!(@ $bar_def, stringify!($bar_def)); };
    (@ $bar_def:expr, $bar_def_str:expr) => {
        impl Foo {
            /// Creates a [Foo] with a `bar` of
            #[doc = $bar_def_str]
            ///.
            fn new() -> Foo { Foo::new_with_bar($bar_def) }

            /// Creates a [Foo] with the provided `bar`.
            fn new_with_bar(bar: usize) -> Foo { Foo { bar } }
        }
    }
}

impl_foo!(3);
```

[image: doc output]

You can use the [paste](https://crates.io/crates/paste) to avoid the redirection:

```
use paste::paste;

struct Foo { bar: usize }

macro_rules! impl_foo {
    ($bar_def:expr) => {
        paste! {
            impl Foo {
                #[doc = "Creates a [Foo] with a `bar` of " $bar_def "."]
                fn new() -> Foo { Foo::new_with_bar($bar_def) }

                /// Creates a [Foo] with the provided `bar`.
                fn new_with_bar(bar: usize) -> Foo { Foo { bar } }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl_foo!(3);
```

In the future, you'll be able to skip the re-direction in the macro (or the usage of `paste!`) by using [`#![feature(extended_key_value_attributes)]`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78835), as described in [vallentin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65427518/155423).

See also:

- The [doc-comment](https://crates.io/crates/doc-comment) crate, which uses this trick to allow documenting an item using an external Markdown file.
- [How to embed a Rust macro variable into documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43353077/155423)

Comment: Ah yes, smart, I hadn't though of re-inlining the `const` into the macro call.

Answer (score 5):

On stable there isn't really an easy solution to doing this, without requiring a specialized macro for each type/method. So the easiest is to fallback to using a `const DEFAULT_BAR` and referencing it in the docs (which you wanted to avoid.)

---

However, there's a rather new nightly feature [`extended_key_value_attributes`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/unstable-book/language-features/extended-key-value-attributes.html) (see [issue #78835](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/78835) and [PR 78837](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/78837).)

Besides requiring one of the latest nightly builds. It will also be slightly cumbersome to use for your use case (in its current state). This is because it either requires the use of literals, which excludes using `const DEFAULT_BAR`. Alternatively, you can use a macro which expands to `5`, which is the cumbersome solution.

```rust
#![feature(extended_key_value_attributes)]

struct Foo {
    bar: usize,
}

macro_rules! default_bar {
    () => {
        5
    };
}

impl Foo {
    /// Creates a [Foo] with a `bar` of
    #[doc = concat!(default_bar!(), ".")]
    fn new() -> Foo {
        Foo::new_with_bar(default_bar!())
    }

    /// Creates a [Foo] with the provided `bar`.
    fn new_with_bar(bar: usize) -> Foo {
        Foo { bar }
    }
}
```

*The above works on rustc 1.50.0-nightly (bb1fbbf84 2020-12-22)*

Note that you have to use [`concat!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.concat.html), as otherwise `default_bar` needs to expand into a string. So if you don't need e.g. `"."`, then just use an empty string, e.g. `concat!("", default_bar!())`.

Comment: I accepted @shepmaster's answer because they do provide a working solution on stable (though it's not exactly pretty) and sadly I can't accept two answers, but thank you very much for the note about `extended_key_value_attributes`, looking forward to it. I upvoted your answer regardless.

Comment: I should probably have clarified, that I meant without creating specialized macros for each type/method. I've clarified that for any future readers. :)